# Create a box of custom rows and columns using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

How to create a custom box of size input by user?
e.g if user inputs 4 columns and 5 rows then 4x5 size box should be generated
and user will able to move to any box with arrow keys

```html
<input type="number" name="row">
<input type="number" name="column">
<button>Create Box</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that to us?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complex ask, as you're moreso asking for a whole program as opposed to asking for help with your own program/code.

To point you in the right direction, you probably want a few things.

1. Store the length and width of the grid as input by a user.
2. Store a users x and y coordinates.
3. Listen to a users key inputs. If they are up and down arrows, set the users y position to be + or - their input. If its left and right, same thing for their x coordinate.
4. Render the grid. If the grid being rendered is the coordinate of the users coordinate, mark it as the users position. Otherwise just render the grid.

A quick bit of semi-pseudocode might look like:

```
const MyGridNavigator = () => {
  const [gridWidth, setGridWidth] = React.useState(4);
  const [gridLength, setGridLength] = React.useState(5);
  const [userPosition, setUserPosition] = React.useState([0,0]);

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
      // up arrow
      setUserPosition([userPosition[0], userposition[1] + 1]);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
      setUserPosition([userPosition[0], userposition[1] - 1]);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
      setUserPosition([userposition[0] - 1, userPosition[1]]);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       // right arrow
       setUserPosition([userposition[0] + 1], userPosition[1]]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
      {
        Array(gridLength).fill().map((y, yIndex) => (
          <div>
            Array(gridWidth).fill().map((x, xIndex) => (
              <div>
                { xIndex === userPosition[0] && yIndex === userPosition[1] ? 'user' : '' } 
              </div>
            ))
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```